# the program exit on the server side when click "OK" on mesenger box of client side.(Connect successfully)

Tags: python

I'm attempting to set up a client-server relationship. The socket seems to be set up correctly as data is transferred from the client to the server at first, but the program exit on the server side when click "OK" on mesenger box. Although i have not closed socket server side

Server code:

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST , PORT))
s.listen()


conn,addr=s.accept()
print("ok")
recv_data=conn.recv(1024)
data=recv_data.decode("utf8")
print(data)
```

Client code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
import socket
def ConnectToServer():
    HOST=entry.get()
    PORT=65432
    test=True
    try:
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((HOST,PORT))
    except Exception as e:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title="Error",message="Error")
        test=False
    if test:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="Notification",message="Connect successfully")


root = tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas1.pack()
entry=tk.Entry()
myButton_connect=tk.Button(text="Connect",command=ConnectToServer)
myButton_TakePic = tk.Button(text="Take screenshot",command=takeScreen, font=10)
myButton_Process = tk.Button(text="Process Running",command=ProcessRunning, font=10)
canvas1.create_window(150,50,window=entry)
canvas1.create_window(150, 100, window=myButton_TakePic)
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=myButton_Process)
canvas1.create_window(250,50,window=myButton_connect)
root.mainloop()
```

In case of successful connection, a message box is displayed and when I press "OK" on that dialog my server side program has ended. Knowing that after the connection is complete, I still send a short message to the server.

Looking forward to everyone's help. I'm a beginner programmer with python

Comment: when you run `pip debug` is the `sys.executable` value same as `python -m "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` ?

Comment: There is no loop in the server code, surely this means it will wait for one message and then accept the message and immediately run out the program and exit.